# Java 8 Generics: Reducing a Stream of Consumers to a single Consumer

Tags: java, generics, java-8, java-stream

How can I write a method for combining a `Stream` of `Consumers` into a single `Consumer` using `Consumer.andThen(Consumer)`?

My first version was:

```
<T> Consumer<T> combine(Stream<Consumer<T>> consumers) {
    return consumers
            .filter(Objects::nonNull)
            .reduce(Consumer::andThen)
            .orElse(noOpConsumer());
}

<T> Consumer<T> noOpConsumer() {
    return value -> { /* do nothing */ };
}
```

This version compiles with JavaC and Eclipse. But it is too specific: The `Stream` cannot be a `Stream<SpecialConsumer>`, and if the `Consumers` are not exactly of type `T` but a super type of it, it cannot be used:

```
Stream<? extends Consumer<? super Foo>> consumers = ... ;
combine(consumers);
```

That won't compile, rightfully. The improved version would be:

```
<T> Consumer<T> combine(Stream<? extends Consumer<? super T>> consumers) {
    return consumers
            .filter(Objects::nonNull)
            .reduce(Consumer::andThen)
            .orElse(noOpConsumer());
}
```

But neither Eclipse nor JavaC compile that:
Eclipse (4.7.3a):

> The type `Consumer` does not define `andThen(capture#7-of ? extends Consumer<? super T>, capture#7-of ? extends Consumer<? super T>)` that is applicable here

JavaC (1.8.0172):

> error: incompatible types: invalid method reference
>   `.reduce(Consumer::andThen)`
>     incompatible types: `Consumer<CAP#1>` cannot be converted to `Consumer<? super CAP#2>`
>   where `T` is a type-variable:
>     `T extends Object` declared in method `<T>combine(Stream<? extends Consumer<? super T>>)`
>   where `CAP#1`,`CAP#2` are fresh type-variables:
>     `CAP#1 extends Object super: T from capture of ? super T`
>     `CAP#2 extends Object super: T from capture of ? super T`

But it should work: Every subclass of Consumer can be used as a Consumer, too. And every Consumer of a super-type of X can consume Xs, too. I tried to add type parameters to each line of the stream version, but that won't help. But if I write it down with a traditional loop, it compiles:

```
<T> Consumer<T> combine(Collection<? extends Consumer<? super T>> consumers) {
    Consumer<T> result = noOpConsumer()
    for (Consumer<? super T> consumer : consumers) {
        result = result.andThen(consumer);
    }
    return result;
}
```

(Filtering out the null values is left out for conciseness.)

Therefore, my question is: How can I convince JavaC and Eclipse that my Code is correct? Or, if it is not correct: Why is the loop-version correct but not the `Stream` Version?

Answer (score 27, accepted):

You use a one-argument [`Stream.reduce(accumulator)`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/stream/Stream.html#reduce-java.util.function.BinaryOperator-) version that has the following signature:

```
Optional<T> reduce(BinaryOperator<T> accumulator);
```

The `BinaryOperator<T> accumulator` can only accept elements of type `T`, but you have:

```
<? extends Consumer<? super T>>
```

I propose you to use a three-argument version of the [`Stream.reduce(...)`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/stream/Stream.html#reduce-U-java.util.function.BiFunction-java.util.function.BinaryOperator-) method instead:

```
<U> U reduce(U identity,
             BiFunction<U, ? super T, U> accumulator
             BinaryOperator<U> combiner);
```

The `BiFunction<U, ? super T, U> accumulator` can accept parameters of two different types, has a less restrictive bound and is more suitable for your situation. A possible solution could be:

```
<T> Consumer<T> combine(Stream<? extends Consumer<? super T>> consumers) {
    return consumers.filter(Objects::nonNull)
                    .reduce(t -> {}, Consumer::andThen, Consumer::andThen);
}
```

The third argument `BinaryOperator<U> combiner` is called only in the parallel streams, but anyway it would be wise to provide a correct implementation of it.

In addition, for a better understanding one could represent the above code as follows:

```
<T> Consumer<T> combine(Stream<? extends Consumer<? super T>> consumers) {

    Consumer<T> identity = t -> {};
    BiFunction<Consumer<T>, Consumer<? super T>, Consumer<T>> acc = Consumer::andThen;
    BinaryOperator<Consumer<T>> combiner = Consumer::andThen;

    return consumers.filter(Objects::nonNull)
                    .reduce(identity, acc, combiner);
}
```

Now you can write:

```
Stream<? extends Consumer<? super Foo>> consumers = Stream.of();
combine(consumers);
```

Answer (score 1):

You have forgotten a small thing in your method definition. It currently is:

```
<T> Consumer<T> combine(Stream<? extends Consumer<? super T>> consumers) {}
```

But you're returing `Consumer<? super T>`. So by changing the return type it almost works. Now you accept an argument `consumers` of type `Stream<? extends Consumer<? super T>>`. Currently it doesn't work, because you're working with possibly different subclasses and implementations of `Consumer<? super T>` (because of the upperbounded wildcard `extends`). You can overcome this, by casting every `? extends Consumer<? super T>` in your `Stream` to a simple `Consumer<? super T>`. Like the following:

```
<T> Consumer<? super T> combine(Stream<? extends Consumer<? super T>> consumers) {
    return consumers
        .filter(Objects::nonNull)
        .map(c -> (Consumer<? super T>) c)
        .reduce(Consumer::andThen)
        .orElse(noOpConsumer());
}
```

This should now work

Comment: How does the loop version allows to return `Consumer<T>`?

Comment: @user7 I am sorry, but I don't understand your question. Do you ask how it currently is possible (so the reason). Or how to fix it that it is possible?

Comment: The type cast to `(Consumer<? super T>)` is equivalent to the assignment to the *enhanced for* loop variable. But the normal *for loop* version of `combine` enables us to return just `Consumer<T>`. I was wondering how

Comment: @user7 I understand now, but is this even desired? Why would you want to return `Consumer<T>` in the first place? And if you want to return an unbounded Consumer you can simply cast it again with `(Consumer<T>)`, which is unchecked but will work

Answer (score 0):

If you have a lot of consumers, applying `Consumer.andThen()` will create a huge tree of consumer wrappers that is processed recursively to call each original consumer.

It might thus be more efficient to simply build a list of the consumers, and create a simple consumer that iterates over them:

```
<T> Consumer<T> combine(Stream<? extends Consumer<? super T>> consumers) {
    List<Consumer<? super T>> consumerList = consumers
            .filter(Objects::nonNull)
            .collect(Collectors.toList());
    return t -> consumerList.forEach(c -> c.accept(t));
}
```

Alternatively, if you can guarantee that the resulting consumer will only be called once, and that the `Stream` will still be valid at that time, you can simply iterate directly over the stream:

```
return t -> consumers
        .filter(Objects::nonNull)
        .forEach(c -> c.accept(t));
```

Comment: Couldn't `c -> c.accept(t)` be replaced with `Consumer::accept`?

Comment: @Alexander No, `forEach` Expects a consumer, i.e. something that takes 1 parameter and returns nothing. `Consumer::accept` would require 2 parameters: the `Consumer` itself (the “`this`”) and the object to consume. In fact you can easily notice it would not be equivalent because `t` would become unused with that method reference.

Comment: Oh yeah, that makes sense

Comment: @Alexander also note that `forEach` actually expects a `Consumer<Consumer<T>>` here